# Remove duplicates from array of objects based on multiple attributes in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array of objects which may contain objects with same attribute values. I am trying to remove the duplicates based on multiple attributes (not just one attribute value)

```
class Font
 attr_accessor :color, :name, :type
end

a = <@color="blue", @name="s", @type="bold">
b = <@color="blue", @name="r", @type="italic"> 
c = <@color="green", @name="t", @type="bold">
d = <@color="blue", @name="s", @type="some_other_type">

fonts = [a, b, c, d]
```

I need to eliminate duplicates based on the values of color, name (I don't care about type)

**what I have tried**

```
uniq_fonts = fonts.uniq { |f| f.name.to_s + f.color.to_s}
```

**is there any cleaner way in which I can achieve the same result?**

Note: 
these are objects and not hashes. I know we could have used:

```
fonts.uniq { |f| f.values_at(:name, :color)}
```

if they were hash

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer? You may discourage other answers and short-circuit those still preparing answers.

Comment: `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are not valid objects, so readers cannot test without going to the trouble of modifying your code. You need to add `def initialize(color, name, type); @color, @name, @type = color, name, type; end`, define `a = Font("blue", "s", "bold")` and similar for  `b`, `c` and `d`.

Comment: I mean `a = Font.new("blue", "s", "bold")`...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try:

```
uniq_fonts = fonts.uniq { |f| [ f.name, f.color ] }
```

You can defined your own `values_at` method like:

```
class Font
  attr_accessor :color, :name, :type

  def values_at *args
    args.map { |method_name| self.public_send method_name }
  end
end
```

And then do like :

```
fonts.uniq { |f| f.values_at(:name, :color)}
```